# Custom annotations to filter entities

Tags: java, annotations, factory

In the example given in http://undancer.com/2013/10/30/Jersey-2.4-User-Guide/#ef.annotations (also code excerpt below) I dont quite understand the use case where this is needed. Could someone please explain the reason for using such custom annotiations ?

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@EntityFiltering
public @interface ProjectDetailedView {

    /**
     * Factory class for creating instances of {@code ProjectDetailedView} annotation.
     */
    public static class Factory
                        extends AnnotationLiteral<ProjectDetailedView>
                        implements ProjectDetailedView {

        private Factory() {
        }

        public static ProjectDetailedView get() {
            return new Factory();
        }
    }
}
```